# How do I increment elapsed time without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need the `elapsed_time` to be updated every second, but it only updates when refreshing the page. I am using `setTimeout` in the script. I need the counter to be updated every second in the script below the following code:

shifts_controller.rb

```
class User::ShiftsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_shift, only: %i[show edit update destroy]

  # GET /shifts or /shifts.json
  def index
    @shifts = current_user.shifts.order(id: :desc)
    @shift  = current_user.shifts.where(clock_out: nil).where.not(clock_in: nil).first
  end

  # GET /shifts/1 or /shifts/1.json
  def show; end

  # GET /shifts/new
  def new
    @shift = Shift.new
  end

  # POST /shifts
  def create
    @shift = Shift.new(user: current_user) # quando criar ja liga ao id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @shift.save
        format.html do
          redirect_to action: 'index', user_id: current_user,
                      notice: 'Shift was successfully created.'
        end
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # GET /shifts/1/edit
  def edit; end

  # PATCH/PUT /shifts/1
  def update
    @shift.set_clock_out
    respond_to do |format|
      if @shift.save
        format.html do
          redirect_to action: 'index', user_id: current_user,
                      notice: 'Shift was successfully updated.'
        end
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /shifts/1 or /shifts/1.json
  def destroy
    @shift.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        redirect_to action: 'index', user_id: current_user,
                    notice: 'Shift was successfully destroyed.'
      end
    end
  end

  private

  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_shift
    @shift = Shift.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
  def shift_params
    params.require(:shift).permit(:clock_in, :clock_out, :user_id, :user_name)
  end
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<div class='container'>
  <% if @shift&.clock_in %>
    <div class='card text-center'>
      <div id='time'>
        <%time_diff = @shift.clock_in - 0.1.second.ago%>
        <%elapsed_time = Time.at(time_diff.to_i.abs).strftime("%H:%M:%S")%>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='card'>
      <br /><%= link_to 'Clock Out', user_shift_path(@shift.id), method: :put, class: "btn btn-success mb-4"%>
    </div>
  <% else %>
    <div class='card'>
      <br /><%= link_to 'Clock In', user_user_shifts_path(current_user.id), method: :post, class: "btn btn-success mb-4"%>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= render 'shifts', shifts: @shifts %>
</div>

<script>
(function timer () {
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "<%=elapsed_time%>";
    setTimeout(timer, 1000); // recalls the function after 1000 ms
})();
</script>
```